# Alternative for UITableView's reloadData()?

Tags: swift, animation, reloaddata

I have a `UISlider` in my table view's reusable cell.
 As soon as the value changes, a custom method `valueChanged()` gets called, which triggers the table view's `reloadData()` method.
The `reloadData()` calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and as soon as the cell in which the slider was changed gets loaded, it animates two constraints which should make it look as if a button is sliding in from the right of the cell.
Basically, the effect I'm trying to create is that as soon as the user starts sliding the `UISlider` the animation takes place and the button appears.
 Here's the catch though: the `UISlider`'s `isContinious` property is set to `true` to make sure the animation happens right away, and doesn't get delayed until the user takes his finger of the slider. Setting `isContinious` to `true`, however, makes it that `reloadData()` (which was inside my custom `valueChanged()`) gets called A LOT OF TIMES with every little slide the user commits.
 After doing some research, and trying out a lot of debugging tactics, I now know that as soon as `reloadData()` gets called, any running animations (which are still animating at the time `reloadData()` gets called) get interrupted and just move to the state it's supposed to be in after the animation is done.

So to recap the scenario:

1) slider moves,
 2) `valueChanged()` triggers `reloadData()`,
 3) animation starts to update layout,
 4) `reloadData()` immediately gets called again ruining the animation which started in step 3.

Everything is happening so fast when `isContinious` is set to `true`, so the animation doesn't get the time it needs to complete before `reloadData()` gets called again. This ruins the animation and makes it look as if the button is just appearing on the screen without animation, even though I know `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` DOES get called and does its job normally. I was wondering if there's a way to refresh a table without calling `reloadData()`, so basically an alternative to this method (I've already tried `reloadCellAtIndexPath` and this has the exact same effect). If not, is there a way to make absolutely sure that an animation finishes without being interrupted by any other layout updating method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is the refresh kills the animation you can defer the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths call until the animation has finished executing.  Normally I would say call it in the completion handler of your animation block but it seems like your value changed may be firing off more than one animation.  Instead when you start the animation also start a timer that will run a block to execute the reload.  If you start a new animation, invalidate the old timer and make a new one.  the reload will only execute when the final animation is done.

```
    var timer = Timer()

    func valueChanged() {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animationDuration, repeats: false) { _ in
            //Call reload here
        }
        //Animate here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't end up using the timer, but you're idea to trigger a timer from the animation block brought me to the idea of just using a custom Boolean which checks whether an animation is still running. I didn't know that the completion block of UIView's animateWithDuration was called AFTER the animation completes. I always used to think it was called immediately after an animation is started and that the Boolean parameter inside the completion block indicated whether or not the animation is still running.

Comment: After I figured this out, it was just a simple matter of creating my own isAnimating Boolean which was set to true when the animation starts and which was set to false in the completion block, AFTER the animation is done. In my valueChanged method (which gets called a bazillion times every second) I just check if isAnimating is set to false, and only run the reloadData() code if it is. Works like a charm. So basically, because I misunderstood the purpose of animateWithDuration's completion block, I made this issue a whole lot more complicated than it turned out to be.